# Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value): invalid 'row.names' length when assigning rowname

Tags: r, parquet

My data frame is derived from a parquet file and read with the arrow package. Parquet automatically reassigns the index as the last column and now I want to re-index the data frame.
How do I assign the last column as the row name?

```
meth_gene <- read_parquet("meth_genesymbol.parquet.gz")
```

df <- meth_gene[,-ncol(meth_gene)]
rownames(df) <- meth_gene[,ncol(meth_gene)]

Error:

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value): invalid 'row.names' length
```

`nrow(df)`
867

`nrow(meth_gene[,ncol(meth_gene)])`
867

Comment: For some reason `meth_gene[, ncol(meth_gene)]` does not return a vector. It should be that `nrow(meth_gene[,ncol(meth_gene)]) == NULL` and `length(meth_gene[,ncol(meth_gene)]) == 867`